# Numpy array of a batch of shifted ranges

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to create a numpy array filled with the values from another array, but each row shifted by one (or some other constant). So for example mapping an array with elements 1,2,3,4,5.... to a 5x5 array, I would expect:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

Currently I'm just running a loop over the original array like:

```
for batch in range(len(foo)-batch_size):
    result[batch,:] = foo[batch:batch+batch_size]
```

But I suspect there's a better and more efficient way to do it in numpy?

Comment: What is the exact input? Does it go up to 9?

Comment: Let's say the input is arbitrary (but large) size and I'm interesting in batching that into arrays of a known size.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `sliding_window_view`

```
a=np.arange(1,10)
np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, 5)
```

→

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Edit (about `copy`)

You had two identical answers, separated by a handful of seconds :D (should have known, when I saw a comment from mozway, that the answer was coming). At least you see that there is some unanimity about it.

Just one remark: the only slight difference is the `copy()` mozway added. And he is right: to do strictly the equivalent of your code (the for loop) that `copy` is needed. Because `sliding_window_view`, as its name indicate, doesn't provide a new array, just a view on the old one.

So if you later modify `a`, it would changes the output array also. Or, if on the contrary, you modify the content of the output array, it also modifies `a`.

That being said, if the fact that your code provides a new copy of the data was just a side effect, and if it is not really a problem to have this view (because you have no intent to modify `a`, or to modify the content of the output array. Or because you don't care of what happen to `a` after, ...), then, being a view is a huge advantage. Because it means that no data is moved or copied (but for a few bytes of metadata).

So, even if `a` contains billions of numbers, `sliding_window_view` is instantaneous. Because all it had to do, is to tweak metadata (shape and strides). While the copy wouldn't be instantaneous.

So, the correct answer to your question is mozway's: to do what you do in python, you need the `copy`. But it is worth considering not doing the copy if it is not needed, because that changes a lot cpu-wise if the array is big.

Comment: You have to get a `copy` if you aim to modify the array else it will be read-only ;)

Comment: @mozway Indeed. I honestly was editing my answer to say exactly that (since I saw that the only visible difference between our answers was you `copy`) before I saw your comment. So, we couldn't agree more.

Comment: Yes, if the goal is to loop or use as temporary values keeping the view is better, I had commented since the original question is "*I'd like to create a **numpy array***", so I assumed this should behave like one ;)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a 1->9 array as input, you can use [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

a = np.arange(1, 10)

N = 5

out = swv(a, N).copy()
```

If you have an arbitrarily large input and want a known size as output:

```
a = np.arange(1, 100)

C = 5  # cols
R = 5  # rows

out = swv(a[:C+(R-1)], C).copy()
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

out = np.broadcast_to(a, (a.shape[0], a.shape[0])) + np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Note that this only works with a range (1,2,3,4…) ;)